# Model of modulator and demodulator in Simulink. Why is MER so lowest?

Tags: signal-analysis, modulation, demodulation, simulink

I created a simple model in Simulink of a quadrature modulator, amplifier and quadrature demodulator. On the oscilloscope(scope in Simulink) and spectrum analyzer the displayed results look normal (at least I think so), but on the constellation diagram I have very low MER, about 15 dB.

Where is mistake?

[image: Block Scheme]
[image: Source of baseband signal]
[[image: Quadrature modulator][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a368P.jpg)
[[image: Add noise][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6f2Iw.jpg)
[image: Amplifier]
[image: Receiver]
[image: Quadrature demodulator]
[image: Constellation diagramm]